# Beginner C++ pointer

Tags: c++, class, pointers, object

I was reading a code snippet and I saw this

```
FILE * infile = fopen("input.wav","rb");
```

I want to ask 2 Questions here.

1. What is `FILE` here. Is it a class, object or anything else.
2. What is `infile` pointing to. I have seen pointers to `int, char` etc. But what is that pointing to.

Comment: _"`FILE` type, capable of holding all information needed to control a C I/O stream"_  (see http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io). `infile` is pointing to a `FILE`.

Comment: What is a type here ? Is it like a variable

Comment: A type is the type of something. `int` is a type, `char` is a type, and `FILE` is a type.

Comment: Just googled for it: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/FILE/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is extremely low quality and does not show any effort at all!

Comment: @gsamaras I don't agree that it should be closed. It asks succinctly what `FILE` represents, and what `infile` points to, both of which are answerable and answered.

Comment: But this shows @hexafraction that he hasn't searched for it, but OK, I am retracting.

Comment: @gsamaras If you had closed it as a duplicate of another question on this site, then that would be a different story. Irrespective of whether I can search for it on the Internet or not, as long as it matches question guidelines in terms of clarity and is not an *on-site* duplicate, there's no point in closing. Your remark seems to show elitism of understanding, while such as question (unless duplicate) is completely acceptable for beginners.

Comment: Hmm good point @hexafraction, will have it in mind, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FILE
```

A structure containing information about a file which is in `stdio.h`

```
infile
```

Points to object returned by `fopen` and its type is `FILE`

Answer (score 1):

> What is FILE here. Is it a class, object or anything else?

- FILE is an object that identifies a stream and contains the information needed to control it, i.e. the position indicator, a pointer to the buffer and all the state indicators.
- *fopen* returns a pointer to a FILE object.
- The memory allocation of the FILE objects is automatically managed, i.e. it is the responsibility of the library to free the resources when the stream has been closed using *fclose* (or when the program terminates normally).
- If you include the < cstdio > header file, these three FILE objects are automatically created:

  1. stdin: standard input stream
  2. stdout: standard output stream
  3. stderr: standard error stream

> What is infile pointing to. I have seen pointers to int, char etc. But what is that pointing to?

It's pointing to that FILE object.

if you want to read from that file pointer do something like this:

```
if (infile == NULL) perror ("Error opening file");
else { /* read */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `FILE` ist the Type of the Object to which `infile` is pointing to.
2. `infile` is pointing to an Object of type `FILE` (which was retuned by `fopen()`)

Comment: `FILE` is not a class, it's a `struct`.

Comment: @Gill Bates i also just realized it :)

Comment: @GillBates well, in C++ keyword `struct` declares class, so he was technically correct.

Answer (score 0):

1. `FILE` is a type coming from C, it's a `struct` used for controlling in and output of files. It contains information about the file handled, certain C functions specialized in handling files use this as a return type or parameter to know what they're dealing with.
2. `infile` is pointing to an object created by `fopen` of type `FILE` that contains information regarding the file you just opened `input.wav`.

Comment: why is FILE in capital letters. I have never seen a struct in capital letters. Can you please explain

Comment: @PawandeepSingh because somebody decided to name it with all capitals. Nothing prevents you from creating struct/class/type alias/variable/etc., named with all capitals.

Answer (score 0):

FILE is object containing information to control a stream and it's used when you want to work with files (fopen, fclose) in c++. The "infile" pointer, points to the memory address where "input.wav" will be placed by the fopen.

Answer (score 0):

FILE
is an object type that identifies a stream and contains the information needed to control it, including a pointer to its buffer, its position indicator and all its state indicators.

reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/FILE/

infile 
points to the start address of this object, in memory

Answer (score 0):

as pointed out by others

1.
`FILE` is a Struct. in simpler terms struct is a data type

2.`infile` is the pointer of FILE type and is pointing to a an audio file which will be in 1's and 0's now depending on the type of variable you use to extract data with the stream will progress according to that data type e.g if you use int it will move 4 bytes and if you use char it will move 1 byte.

ps i wouldnt recommend using .wav for uderstanding the concepts make a simple txt and try to extract chars strings int and stuff